# Polymer how to use value of slider in next page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, polymer

I am using Polymer and PHP in my project. 
I am using a paper-slider in one page and using AJAX to transfer it's value to the next page where it will be used in PHP code for some operations. 
My code is :

For script in Page1.php

```
     <script>
           var flowPercent = document.querySelector('#flow');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/Page3.php',
      type : 'POST',
      data : {x:flowPercent.value},
      success: function( data ) {
      console.log( data );
      }

    });

    // custom transformation: scale header's title
    var titleStyle = document.querySelector('.title').style;
    addEventListener('core-header-transform', function(e) {
      var d = e.detail;
      var m = d.height - d.condensedHeight;
      var scale = Math.max(0.75, (m - d.y) / (m / 0.25)  + 0.75);
      titleStyle.transform = titleStyle.webkitTransform =
          'scale(' + scale + ') translateZ(0)';

    });    
  </script>
```

For navigating to next page :

```
<paper-button span raised class="colored" onclick="window.open('Page2.php','_parent');" layout center horizontal>Next</paper-button>
```

In Page2.php to retrieve the value :

```
<?php echo $_POST['x'];?>
```

I have imported this in Page1.php :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I do not see any value echoed in Page2. I would like to see the value of the slider selected in the previous page. How do I achieve this ?
Do let me know if any other code is required to be posted here .

Thanks !